# JAVA - Map an expression with ModelMapper, but without setter

Tags: java, collections, setter, modelmapper

I'm using ModelMapper to map a JPA entities to DTO. I have Collections on entities
The dto is generated by wsimport from a wsdl file, but the collection's setters aren't generate

```
public class sampleEntity{
    private String name;
    private Collection<String> list;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    

    public Collection<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(Collection<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

public class sampleDTO{
    private String name;
    private Collection<String> list;

    //getters & setters

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Collection<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
//no collection setters with jaxb!!! Use getList().add()

}
```

I use a simple MapperUtils to map entities and dto

```
public class MapperUtils {

    private static ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    static {
        modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
    }

    private MapperUtils() {
    }

    public static <D, T> D map(final T entity, Class<D> outClass) {
        return modelMapper.map(entity, outClass);
    }

    public static <D, T> List<D> mapAll(final Collection<T> entityList, Class<D> outCLass) {
        return entityList.stream().map(entity -> map(entity, outCLass)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static <S, D> D map(final S source, D destination) {
        modelMapper.map(source, destination);
        return destination;
    }

}
```

So how to use ModelMapper to use DTO.getXXXX.add () if Entity.XXXX is a Collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any idea if ModelMapper is able to support getList().add() call over a destination during the mapping.

Here are 2 approached that might solve your problem.

Approach 1: enable the field matching

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration()
    .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true);
```

Approach 2:

Try to generate the setter code with wsimport.